# Extracting text from a string

Tags: ios, swift2, text-extraction

Hi I have this error I keep coming up with that says Value of type '[String]' has no member 'characters'

Here is my code:

```
let sentence = "the mans states of this game are Jumping: 132.4 and Speed: 142.192"


func matchesForRegexInText(regex: String!, text: String!) -> [String] {

do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: [])
    let nsString = text as NSString
    let results = regex.matchesInString(text,
        options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length))
    return results.map { nsString.substringWithRange($0.range)}
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    return []
 }
}

let sentJumping = matchesForRegexInText("Jumping:\\s+\\d+.\\d+", text: sentence)
print(sentJumping)

let gallNumb = sentJumping.characters.split(":").map{ String($0) } // The error I'm getting is on this line
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDITED

You need to transform the string array `sentJumping` in to a `String` prior to trying to using the string method `characters`. As it is now, `sentJumping` is of type `[String]` (array). One method could be to reduce the array into one string, as the sum of all string entries in the string array.

Try replacing your last line of code with the following

```
let gallNumb = sentJumping.reduce("", combine: +).characters.split(":").map{ String($0) }
```

Note that by using `sentJumping[0]` solution as recommended in the other answer, you will just get the first entry of the array (in your specific example: the array has only one entry, ok), and, *if the array is empty*, give you a runtime exception.

Comment: Whoever down voted my initial answer (without feedback), please re-read this edited answer and see if it is possibly no longer of low quality.

Comment: Aren't "drive-by downvotes" maddening? Who does that?!? (Your answer looks good to me.)

Comment: Indeed! To someones defence, I thought a good while on my initial non-edited answer, and I think it could possibly motivate a minor down vote (if using the logic that !upvote = down vote). I can appreciate a motivated down vote, but I'm very grateful if the down vote comes with some feedback, rather than by drive-by! (the former; in which case the down-voted answerer---in this case, me---can also learn something).

Comment: I wasn't able to see the initial non-edited answer, before you posted but while both worked you at least explained the concept. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: I’d written up a comment explaining my downvote (your original approach would have just provided the array’s description, e.g. `["a", "b"]`, which has a lot of unwanted extra characters), but by the time I’d finished that you’d already deleted the answer. This is much better—thanks! Upvoted.

Comment: @NoahWitherspoon Ah yeah I realised one I put my first answer into a playground that it contained some extra characters that I had not expected, thanks for your comment now!

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
let gallNumb = sentJumping[0].characters.split(":").map{ String($0) }
```

Your function returns an array. You need to use `[0]` to retrieve the result you want.